# Variable Assignment - OpenCV/Python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.0

Newbie here! I am trying to apply a filter on an image and I want to show the original and the filtered images in two windows. The problem I am having with the results is that the original image (img_1) will get filtered as well even if I apply modified channels to img_2 only. I know if I trigger imshow of img_1 before merging channels of img_2, it will be fine. I am still confused as to why img_1 gets changed even if the filter is applied to img_2.

```
import cv2
img_1 = cv2.imread('C:/xxxx')
img_2 = img_1

b,g,r = cv2.split(img_2)

cv2.addWeighted(b, 0.5, g, 0.5, 0, b) 
cv2.merge((b,b,r), img_2)

cv2.imshow('Original', img_1)
cv2.imshow('Filtered with RC', img_2)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

They are referencing to the same image as you wrote `img_2 = img_1`.
You can copy the image this way to get the desired output: `img_2 = img_1.copy()`